# The best way to store passwords in database to other services

Tags: security, passwords, store

I need to integrate different services with my application. What is the best way to store credentials to other services? I know that i sould not store passwords as plain text by i don't know is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you, to use an secure symmetric encryption standard like aes. At the start of your application, the user should enter a password. You can simply use this password to encrypt and decrypt the credentials or you could take the hash of the password and use that hash for encryption and decryption.